# How can I filter an array but with one excepcetion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to filter an array so I am not sending any falsy values.

```
const notFalsyItems = my_team.filter(
  ({ about, email, mobile, last_name, country_code_mobile }) =>
    about && email && mobile && last_name && country_code_mobile,
);

UpdateMyTeamAPICall(notFalsyItems);
```

But within this array there is an item which I may send even if it’s `null` or not; which is `photo_id`.

So I need to do include `photo_id` even if it’s falsy or not in -> `notFalsyItems`

What can I do?

Comment: You don't have to do anything, the code will work as is?

Comment: It is unclear what `photo_id` would be in your code. You may always complement your filter condition, like `(...) || (photo_id === null)` ( which is an artificial example since, as Jonas hinted at, you simply do not need to include `photo_id`in your tests (unless you want to reject when it is `undefined` but let it pass when it is `null`).

Comment: @JonasWilms is correct, the `photo_id` isn't in your filter and therefore a falsy value will not affect the filtering

Answer (score 1):

You can have a more complex function to filter it. [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) allows it.

```js
const my_team = [
  // should pass
  { id: false, about: true, email: true },
  // should not pass
  { id: true, about: false, email: true },
  // should pass
  { id: true, about: true, email: true }
]

// Note that I actually not even changed your code
//(removed some attrs to make it short actually)
//just made it more explicity.
// id will not even be looked at.
const notFalsyItems = my_team.filter(team => {
    const { about, email } = team
    
    // If you return true, item will be added
    // if you return false, item will be skipped
    return about && email
  }
    
);

console.log(notFalsyItems)
```

Comment: I need to send photo_id regardless if it is `null` or not. `photo_id` should always be sent.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanging you correctly I think all you need to do is a change in your condition as below:

```
const notFalsyItems = my_team.filter(
  ({ about, email, mobile, last_name, country_code_mobile, photo_id }) =>
    {
      //photo_id will always be available whether null or not
      return (about && email && mobile && last_name && country_code_mobile)
    }
);
```

Comment: Then it will always be true if photo_id exists
```false && false || true // true```

Comment: then you can skip the photo_id in the condition and only use the ones you really need

Comment: Nope. I need to send photo_id regardless if it is `null` or not. `photo_id` should always be sent.

Comment: photo_id is being sent just not included in the returning true or false